# target disk is too small on reboot

Tags: macos, boot

I'm trying to reinstall OSx on my `macbookpro 13 2010`. Right when it was about to install, I get the error that `target disk is too small`. I reboot it again and open the terminal and type:

`diskutil list`

And get this result:
[result of typing **diskutil list**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qEtZ.jpg)
I see that `diskutil` has many helpful commands which can erase or merge volumes and disks. However, I'm not sure which ones are safe or exactly how to go about doing this. What should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these *steps* and let me know if it helped:

1. `diskutil list`
2. `diskutil apfs deleteContainer disk0s2` - this will delete the apfs partition that is currently active.
3. again, `diskutil list`
4. `diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk0 gpt apfs macOSX 250` - this will create a new partition for you named **macOSX**

Now try to re install the OS to this drive. I am sure it will succeed. Revert back if any more queries exist.

Comment: When I try `diskutil apfs deleteContainer disk0s2` I get the error: `Error: Starting APFS Container deletion: not a valid target disk type for this APFS delete operation (-69600)`

Comment: Also I'm curious why `diskutil list`. Is this so I see what's happening to the disks as I modify/delete them?

Comment: `diskutil list` is done to see a list of all the disks you have in your machine. Since you are getting that error `not a valid target disk type for this APFS delete operation`, your disk seems to be not of the _APFS_ format. If I'm right it is _JHFS_. I suggest you try reinstalling the system, and on the `Install` screen, go to '`Utilities > Disk Utility` and choose your disk and `Erase` it. Now try reinstalling to the same disk. That should help.

Comment: I erased the disk using diskutility now I only have one internal physical volume called `os base system`. When I try to install the mac Os after that I get the message that the  `locked`. Also when I try `diskutil apfs deleteContainer disk0s2` I get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I found an easy solution for this.

First erase the disk with disk utility using erase and then just create another partition on it and install the OS to the new partition. Don't know why but it works.